# Silverlight hardware-accelerated playback is greyed-out - How do I enable it?

Tags: windows-xp, gpu, silverlight, netflix, hardware-acceleration

I am trying to play Netflix videos (which only play via Silverlight), but they play choppy because Silverlight's `hardware-accelerated playback` is disabled.

(video playback on WMP11 and VLC is flawless, so I know beyond certainty that my built-in video card's hardware is perfectly capable of hardware-accelerated playback)

[image]

I have the latest & greatest Silverlight version: [5.1.10411.0](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/12/10/Why-Silverlight-5s-3D-is-%28almost%29-useless.aspx)

And I tried to "un-grey-it-out" via the Registry's [GPUVideoDecodeEnabled](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/245078.aspx/1) and [UpdateMode](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/612857.aspx), but that didn't help.

Is there any way to "[un-grey-it-out](http://goo.gl/MdxOQ)"?

Comment: I suspect the text in the bottom of that window is the answer.  Google returned no results. What graphics card is in your HTPC?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to find definitive system requirements for Silverlight but the info is pretty sparse.  Check out the following requirements from the MSDN site -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833062%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

This MSDN Blog gives additional detail -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahul/archive/2010/06/09/silverlight-graphics-and-hardware-acceleration.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 1):

Are you the administrator for this computer? Per the message at the bottom of the dialog box, you may have to enable it on the admin account first.